# Searching for list of tables from tab when only partial names of the tables are present

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the list of tables from tab , but I only have partial names of the tables :-

For example:-
`SELECT COLUMN_NAME1 FROM TABlE_NAME  ;`

This returns a list of data : A,B,C,D

The aforementioned data is actually part of a table's name like tableprefix_**A**_tablesuffix.

I want the list of these tables from TAB or user_tables using partial name available.

Comment: So, you want to search the table name based on the row data of a particular table?

Comment: Yes Ravi.. Two tweaks. Its table names and not not table name . There are more than one table. Second its column data. That column data contains keywords which are part of table names in user_tables. Refer to the example I gave in question and to Mureinik's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be ok:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME1 PATTERN, U.TABLE_NAME
FROM TABLE_NAME T, USER_TABLES U
WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(U.TABLE_NAME, '(^|_)' || T.COLUMN_NAME1 || '($|_)') != 0
```

It retrieves patterns like `A_%`, `%_A_%`, `%_A`.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel for the help. This is what I was looking for. I used the concept provided and modified the query according to my need.

Answer (score 0):

How about joining the two with the `like` operator:

```
SELECT u.table_name
FROM   user_tables
JOIN   table_name t ON u.table_name like '%' || t.column_name1 || '%'
```

Comment: Mureinik I am not sure if we are on the same page. Using the output of the first query (where output is suppose A,B,C,D) I need to check for all the tables which contain those keywords from user_tables/tab. So the output would be something like this:- foo_A_bar1, foo_B_bar2, C_foobar3, foobar4_D.